# How can I do this in Qlikview?

Tags: join, qlikview

I have a "All_Data" table that contains an "HR Manager" column and it contains "Employee Name".
I need to get the rows that does **NOT** fulfill the following join (meaning the ones that are missing from the joined table).

```
HR_Manager:
Load [HR Manager] as [HR Full Name]
Resident All_Data;

inner Join(HR_Manager)
Load [Full Name] as [HR Full Name]
Resident All_Data;
```

Does anyone know how can I do this in Qlikview?

Thx,
Lena

Answer (score 1):

You beat me to it by 1 minute Francesco, but you did forget the semi-colon on the end ;)

```
HR_Manager:
Load [HR Manager] as [HR Full Name]
Resident All_Data;

inner Join(HR_Manager)
Load [Full Name] as [HR Full Name]
Resident All_Data;

AllTheOthers:

Load [Full Name] as [Employee Name]
resident All_Data
where not exists ([Full Name]);
```

If that's not quite what you're looking for, the following may work instead

```
HR_Manager:
Load [HR Manager] as [HR Managers that are not employees]
Resident All_Data
Where not exists ([HR Manager],[Full Name]);
```

This will create a table of all the people that exist in the HR Manager field, but do not appear in the Full Name field.

Hope this helps,

James.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the [Full Name] is the "Employee Name" field you mention in your text.

Is this what you are trying to express?:

```
New_Table:
Load [HR Manager] as [HR Full Name]
Resident All_Data
Where [HR Manager] <> [Full Name];
```

Cheers,
Simon

Comment: Not exactly, what you describe will get me the rows where those two are not equal, what I need is HR Manager that doesn't exist as an employee.
If it where in SQL I would use "except" between the original table and the result of the join

Answer (score 0):

```
HR_Manager:
Load [HR Manager] as [HR Full Name]
Resident All_Data;

inner Join(HR_Manager)
Load [Full Name] as [HR Full Name]
Resident All_Data;

AllTheOthers:

Load [Full Name] as [Employee Name]
resident All_Data
where not exists ([Full Name])
```